# Describe a neighborhood of a given interior point

Tags: complex-analysis

Before I ask the question, I would like to define some terms.

A point $z_0$ is said to be an interior point of a subset $S$ of the complex plane if there exists some neighborhood of $z_0$ that lies entirely within $S$. If every point $z$ of a set $S$ is an interior point, then $S$ is said to be an open set. For example, the inequality $\Re(z) > 1$ defines a right half-plane, which is an open set. All complex numbers $z = x + iy$ for which $x > 1$ are in this set.

But does not it depend on the value of $y$? Suppose $z_0=1.1+2i$. How can we describe a neighborhood in this case? Clearly the length between $z_0$ and some points should be less than some value, but what is this value? Please help me.

Comment: Yes. In general, the neighborhood you choose for each point will depend on its position (if you're trying to use balls). So if you have $z_0=1.1+2i$, then you can take the ball centered at $z_0$ with radius $.05$, for example.

Comment: and which point is boundary point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One kind of neighborhood is an open disk around $z_0$.  In your example, $z_0$ is $0.1$ from the line $Re(z)=1$, so any disk of radius less than $0.1$ will work.  It doesn't depend on the imaginary part ($y$) because the division line doesn't depend on $y$.

If the set were the points for which $2Re(z) \gt Im(z)$, it is again an open set.  Your $z_0=1.1+2i$ is in this set too.  But the distance from the dividing line depends on $y$ in this case because the line is sloping.

Comment: and distance is up to me?if i see that all points,distance  between which is less then $0.03$ for example?

Comment: @dato Yes. There are many neighborhoods that will suffice. You just need to find one.

Comment: in generally,if i say that criteria is $Re(z)>1$,it means that  maximum radius could be difference between   real parts of  complex numbers?or in my case maximum radius is difference between $1.1$ and $1$  ?and also please tell me what would be boundary point

Comment: In your original question, the closest boundary point is $1+2i$.  In my example of $2Re(z)\gt Im(z)$ you need to find the perpendicular to the boundary line, which has slope -1/(slope of boundary line).  Here the boundary is $y=2x$ with slope $2$, so the perpendicular has slope $-\frac 12$.  The line through $(1.1,2)$ is then $y=-\frac12 x + 2.55$  You can solve this with $y=2x$ to find the intersection point, then compute the distance of that point from $(1.1,2)$  Any disk around $1.1+2i$ with a radius less than that will be in the set.